# Contour plot from list of 4D points

Tags: plotting

I have tried everything I think but I could not obtain a 3D contour plot from a list. Here is my code. Could you help me find the mistake I made?

```
data = 
  {{0., 0.0416667, 0.0103448, -22952.9}, {0., 0.0416667, .012069,-27172.}, 
   {0., 0.0416667, 0.0137931, -31593.6}, {0., 0.0416667,0.0155172, -36243.9}, 
   {0., 0.0416667, 0.0172414, -41149.6}, {0.,0.0416667,0.0189655, -46337.7}}

ListContourPlot3D[data]
```

Unfortunately, the only thing I get is an empty box.

Comment: All the x, y, and function values are zero, so it's unclear what kind of output you expect.

Comment: Sorry @C.E, I have taken a part of my list to summarize my problem. Here, you could find the values of the fourth column which are not equal to zero. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In the updated list, all of the x and y values are identical: `0., 0.0416667`.

Answer (score 3):

```
data = {{0., 0.0416667, 0.0103448, -22952.9}, {0., 0.0416667, 
    0.012069, -27172.}, {0., 0.0416667, 0.0137931, -31593.6}, {0., 0.0416667, 
    0.0155172, -36243.9}, {0., 0.0416667, 0.0172414, -41149.6}, {0., 
    0.0416667, 0.0189655, -46337.7}};
```

Since all of the `x` values are identical and all of the `y` values are identical, you can plot in 2D.

```
Legended[
 ListLinePlot[data[[All, 3 ;;]],
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {z, f}),
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  Epilog -> {Text[StringForm["{x, y} = ``",
      NumberForm[data[[1, {1, 2}]], 3]],
     {0.016, -15000}]}],
 BarLegend[{"Rainbow", MinMax@data[[All, 4]]}]]
```

[image]